# Why do we use get_filename() in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, get

I've recently started learning how to build Wordpress themes.

The tutorial I was following was using get_filename() instead of include/require - basically if I wanted to retrieve footer.php, I would use

I am struggling to find any documentation that covers why get_filename() works and whether it has any superiority over include or require - and especially want to find out whether get_filename() suffers from the same security issues as include and require.

I appreciate this may not have a simple linear answer to apologies if this doesn't quite fit the mould for StackOverflow questions (I'm new over here). Any advice on the matter is much appreciated.

Frustratingly this question has been marked as a duplicate that has already been answered but the moderator appears to be misinterpreting my question here.

Thanks

Comment: @jay why have you marked this as a duplicate? Did you read what I wrote?

Comment: Yes. Did you read the documentation for`get_filename()`? No - you didn't because there are no docs for this non-existent function in PHP. There are some other `get_file...` functions, all of which return a string. Includes and requires allow the code in the remote file to be executed as part of your current script.

Comment: Thank you for the response :) - I think I may have found the answer to my question over at Codex.Wordpress but thanks anyways @Jay